# How do I take a screenshot from the terminal?

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

I am using Lubuntu 14.04.

How do I - using the command line - take a screenshot of a window or my desktop?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>moved the OP's answer embedded in the question to here as a community wiki</sub>

In Lubuntu the command-line entry to take a screenshot is the following:

`lxsession-default screenshot window`

Answer (score 0):

In Xubuntu

For fullscreen

```
xfce4-screenshooter -f
```

For region

```
xfce4-screenshooter -r
```

For active window

```
xfce4-screenshooter -w
```

To save to a directory, with a region

```
xfce4-screenshooter -rs ~/Desktop
```

To copy to clipboard, with a region

```
xfce4-screenshooter -rc
```

All available options are detailed in the man page
    man xfce4-screenshooter

Answer (score 0):

In Lubuntu you can use the following commands to take screenshot..

take screenshot
`scrot`

take screenshot after some delay (5 sec)

`scrot -d 5`